# Spring Integration DSL: Apply aggregator only based on message count and send to Http end point in parellel

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am totally new to Spring Injection. I am looking for the below logic:

1. Messages are posted to a Queue Channel(This can be changed). I just want to do throttling
2. Using the Spring Injection aggregate 2 messages(no Correlation is required) from the queue and send it to the Http Endpoint as a single message. The http endpoint can be slow sometimes. Hence I want 10 parellel threads to be processing the messages in parellel. Each thread, pick 2 messages from queue and send to Http endpoint.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow myFlow() {
       return IntegrationFlow.from(Constants.INBOUND_CHANNEL)
        .bridge(e ->         e.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(1000).maxMessagesPerPoll(5).taskExecutor(taskExecutor1())))
        .log()
        .aggregate(a -> a.correlationStrategy(m -> m != null).releaseStrategy(g -> g.size() == 2)
                .expireGroupsUponCompletion(true).expireGroupsUponTimeout(true).async(true))
        .log().handle(a -> {
            //Add code here to send the data to Http end point which takes around 5 secs.
            System.out.println("Thread Sleeping on ThreadId : " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, e -> e.async(true)).get();
}

    @Bean
    TaskExecutor taskExecutor1() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        return taskExecutor;
    }

  @Bean(name = Constants.INBOUND_CHANNEL)
  public QueueChannel inboundFilePollingChannel() {
      return new QueueChannel(100);
  }
```

The above code is running fine. But the aggregate logic looks to be happening in sequence. Until the aggregated group is released, the other threads of task executors are not picking the messages for processing and not sending the messages to Http Endpoint.

Any hints on whats the approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all an `async(true)` doesn't help if service activator does not return `CompletableFuture` or Reactive Streams `Publisher`.

Then you have this problem: `correlationStrategy(m -> m != null)`, which always returns `true` for all the messages you send to this aggregator. The further logic of the `AggregatingMessageHandler` does this:

```
    UUID groupIdUuid = UUIDConverter.getUUID(correlationKey);
    Lock lock = this.lockRegistry.obtain(groupIdUuid.toString());
```

And that is locked until we done with the current message. Therefore even if you produce to this aggregator from different threads, you still do aggregation sequential and blocked way. Just because you use the same `Lock` instance for all the messages according to your correlation strategy.

And one more problem: doesn't looks like you call an HTTP service in parallel. You need to think about adding an `ExecutorChannel` in between `aggregate()` and `handle()`. This way the result of an aggregator (two messages) would be produced to another thread and the current one will be freed to deal with the next message for aggregation.

We don't have an out-of-the-box component to just emit a number of messages in order they arrive: we have only logic based on a correlation key: `AggregatingMessageHandler`, `ResequencingMessageHandler`, `CorrelatingMessageBarrier` and `FluxAggregatorMessageHandler`.

I think you still may rely on a sequential releasing in the aggregator with that your generic correlation key, but you don't need a `taskExecutor` on the poller since it does not have any effects, but rather use a `channel(c -> c.executor())` after an aggregator. This way you'll see parallel calls to your HTTP service with 2 messages each.